# Creating lists from trees which preserve the structure of the tree

Tags: python, tree, huffman-code

For an application I'm writing, I need to  test the branches of a Huffman tree for a certain properrty. To that end, I've thought about querying a node, and returning a flat list which contains sublists representing the items in each branch.

For example, if I had this tree:

```
-a
|-b
|-c
|-d
```

I'd like to create a list by querying the topmost item ('a') and return the following list:

```
[[a],[b,c,d]]
```

If I queried the second leaf ('b') I want to return:

```
[[b].[c,d]]
```

etc

So far I'm storing my tree as a tuple like so:

```
(1.0,(0.5,(0.25, (0.125,'d'),(0.125,'c')),(0.25,'b')),(0.5,'a'))
```

I have a function which prints the information on the leaves:

```
def printTree(tree, prefix = ''):
    if len(tree) == 2:
        print tree[1], prefix
    else:
        printTree(tree[1], prefix + '0')
        printTree(tree[2], prefix + '1')
```

I've tried creating a function which replaces the print statements with list() statements, but that didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could go about this?

Comment: instead of print just do a `list.append()` call to the list you are trying to create.

Comment: What does "left" and "right" mean in your little tree diagram? I couldn't udnerstand this

Comment: @OfirIsrael from the 1st node the 'a' wold be the left and the rest would be the right

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for something like:

```
def printTree(tree, prefix = '', res=[]):
    if len(tree) == 2:
        res.append((tree[1], prefix))
        print tree[1], prefix
    else:
        printTree(tree[1], prefix + '0', res=res)
        printTree(tree[2], prefix + '1', res=res)
    return res
```

`res` will hold your results while in the recursion, and at the end it'd return.

With your *tree* this will return: `[('d', '000'), ('c', '001'), ('b', '01'), ('a', '1')]`
, was that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I wanted something that will return the branches of a tree (or the branches off a node) as a list of two lists: for example [[a],[b,c,d]] or [[b],[c,d]].